# How best to set up a triple-boot with MacOS Sierra, Windows 10, and Linux Mint on 2016 iMac?

Tags: linux-mint, osx, windows

The current partition setup is Mac OS (741gb), Win 10(250gb), Mac OS Recovery (<1gb).

I plan on shrinking Mac OS to leave 250gb free or 120gb if not enough free space.

I want to set up a minimal Linux to test apps created by Xojo. If the system only has 8gb of RAM, should I create a swap partition? If so, how large?

Answer (score -1):

Your swap should be at least 1 tp 1.5 GB, but no more than 4GB.